# calculate average for group based on element value

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns: Model and Price

```
Model       Price
Pilot       30
Civic       20
Highlander  10
Corolla     40
Rav4        25
```

I know that Pilot and Civic is Honda car while Highlander, Corolla, Rav4 is Toyota.
I want to calculate, say average price for Honda group (30+20)/2 and Toyota (10+40+25)/3.

Output table:

```
Mode    Average_price
Honda   25
Toyota  25
```

My problem is that I am NOT allowed to create new table or new column in existing table.

Thus I think somewhere in the query I need to list all condition say

```
IF Model in ('Pilot','Civic') then Manufacturer='Honda' else if Model in ('Highlander','Corolla','Rav4') then Manufacturer='Toyota'
Then average by Manufacturer.
```

Can anyone please help me to write a query?

Thank you,

Harry

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select 
    case 
        when model in ('Pilot', 'Civic') then 'Honda'
        when model in ('Highlander', 'Corolla', 'Rav4') then 'Toyota'
    end mode,
    avg(price) avg_price
from mytable
group by
    case 
        when model in ('Pilot', 'Civic') then 'Honda'
        when model in ('Highlander', 'Corolla', 'Rav4') then 'Toyota'
    end
```

Some databases extend the SQL standard by allowing the use of aliases in the `group by` clause (eg MySQL), so you can simplify it as follows:

```
group by mode
```

Comment: I try your query in the below place and an error show up.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_drop_table

SELECT 
  case 
    when CategoryName in ('Beverages','Condiments','Confections') then 'top'
    when CategoryName in ('Products','Grains/Cereals','Meat/Poultry') then 'mid'
  end mode
  sum(CategoryID)
from Categories
group by
case 
    when CategoryName in ('Beverages','Condiments','Confections') then 'top'
    when CategoryName in ('Products','Grains/Cereals','Meat/Poultry') then 'mid'
  end

Comment: @Harry: there was a missing comma between `mode` and `avg(price)` - just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

How about a common table expression?

```
;WITH hondaCTE AS (
    SELECT 'Honda' AS [make]
    ,   SUM(ct.Price) / COUNT(1) AS [avg_price]
    FROM car_table AS ct
    WHERE ct.Model IN ('pilot','civic')
)
, toyotaCTE AS (
    SELECT 'Toyota' AS [make]
    ,   SUM(ct.Price) / COUNT(1) AS [avg_price]
    FROM car_table AS ct
    WHERE ct.Model NOT IN ('pilot','civic') -- Exclude Honda models
)
-- Union results
SELECT * FROM hondaCTE
UNION
SELECT * FROM toyotaCTE
```

Output:

```
make    avg_price
Honda   25
Toyota  25
```

Comment: I suggest using `UNION ALL` instead of plain `UNION`, so the RDBMS does not have to introduce processing for handling duplicates.

Comment: Why would there be duplicates?

Comment: In this case there are no duplicates, but the RDBMS does not know that, so it must ensure that there are none doing `UNION`, so spending processing resources. (As `UNION` is a set operator, so it's required by SQL specification to return no duplicates.) When you tell it to do `UNION ALL`, you tell it not to care about any duplication (to just concatenate the data sets), so in this case it knows, that it does not have to spend resources on this. This is basically a choice between telling DB  `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (X UNION ALL Y)` (== `UNION`) or `(X UNION ALL Y)`.

Comment: Thank you.  Your summary is very good and I appreciate you taking the time to post it.  Indeed, I should have clarified why I selected `union` vs `union all` and will do so moving forward.